# Paypal iOS SDK UI issues on iOS13

Tags: ios, paypal

I'm seeing the following problems with the PayPal iOS SDK:

- The PayPal UI is not correct.
- The login text is sort of overlapping.
- Also,  once you have selected a payment method i.e. card or logged
  into paypal you are not able to change the payment method.  There are
  button duplication etc as well.

[image: Check Issue Screen Shot]

Comment: Screenshots where?

Comment: Now i Edit my post and add link of screen shot.